# Group acting properly and cocompactly by isometries on a metric space has finitely many conjugacy classes of point stabilizers

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

*Let $\Gamma$ be a group acting properly and cocompactly by isometries on a metric space $X$. Then, $\Gamma$ has finitely many conjugacy classes of point stabilizers.*

The proof of this well-known result goes like this:

Let $x\in X$, and let $\Gamma_x$ denote the stabilizer of $x$ under the $\Gamma$-action. Since the action is cocompact, there exists a compact subset $K \subset X$ such that the $\Gamma$-translates of $K$ cover $X$. Hence there exists $\gamma \in \Gamma$ such that $x \in \gamma K$.

Since $\gamma^{-1} \Gamma_x \gamma = \Gamma_{\gamma^{-1}x}$, and $\gamma^{-1}x \in K$, for each $\alpha \in \gamma^{-1} \Gamma_x \gamma$, $\alpha K \cap K \neq \emptyset$.

Usually the proof concludes by saying that the result follows by properness of the action. I'm not sure how this follows, since we have only shown that *for a specific element*  $\gamma \in \Gamma$, $\gamma^{-1} \Gamma_x \gamma$ is contained in a finite set. Wouldn't we have to show that this holds for *all* $\gamma \in \Gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what is shown so far, it follows that for each $x \in X$ there exists $y \in K$ such that $\Gamma_x$ is conjugate to $\Gamma_y$.

So, what's left to check is that as $y$ varies over $K$, there are only finitely many different subgroups of the form $\Gamma_y$.

This will follow if one can prove that the set of elements
$$\bigcup_{y \in K} \Gamma_y = \bigcup_{y \in K} \{\delta \in \Gamma \mid \delta(y)=y\}
$$
is finite.

And that will follow if one can prove that the set of elements
$$\{\delta \in \Gamma \mid \delta(K) \cap K \ne \emptyset\}
$$
is finite. Well, that's the definition of properness of the $\Gamma$ action on $X$, applied to the compact set $K$.

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to process one thing: Assuming there are finitely many sets of the form $\Gamma_y$ as $y$ varies over $K$, and assuming for each $x\in X$, $\Gamma_x$ is conjugate to $\Gamma_y$ for some $y\in Y$, why must there only be finitely many sets of the form $\Gamma_x$ for $x\in X$?

Comment: One is not asked to prove that there are only finitely many sets of the form $\Gamma_x$ for $x \in X$. One is instead asked to prove that as $x \in X$ varies, the subgroups $\Gamma_x$ are all conjugate to one of finitely many subgroups. There will still most likely be *infinitely many different subgroups* $\Gamma_x$; it's just that they will fall into finitely many conjugacy classes.

Comment: Ohh of course, and since every conjugacy class must contain $\Gamma_y$ for some $y \in K$, and since $\Gamma_y$ can only be contained in at most one conjugacy class, there can only be finitely many conjugacy classes